# Supervised learning for audio files with uncertain labels

Tags: machine-learning, svm, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, semi-supervised-learning

There exists a collection of audio files, each 30 seconds long. Such an audio file contains the recording of the manufacturing of a certain small piece in a machine. After manufacturing the piece, it is built in in another larger piece whose quality is tested and classified in good / bad. The quality of the larger piece is not only determined by the first part, but by other parts and the building process as well: it is thus not possible to say whether the first smaller piece was good/bad. The only thing I know is that with a probability of x%, a faulty small first piece leads to a bad larger piece, with x somewhere between 30-40%.

I need to build a model which takes the manufacturing audio file of the small piece as input and predicts whether it is good/bad. Are there any papers even remotely related to this kind of task? My basic questions are:
1) If I use supervised learning, is there any way I can assign a "credibility" of the labels? Each audio file is labeled, but the label has only a probability y of being right.
2) Is supervised learning even the right direction here or how would you approach this kind of problem?
3) How would you even test the correctness of the predictor, apart from just analysing what percentage of larger parts is good/bad based on the predictions vs the real analysis of the larger parts?

I would be thankful for any kind of recommendation or comment either about the questions or on how you would approach the problem.